# Witness a cruel moment [in/of] nature?

Tags: word-choice

I'm imagining a scene where a few wolves attack a few deers.

What would be the correct form here?

**I witnessed a cruel moment [in] nature.**

or

**I witnessed a cruel moment [of] nature.**?

Comment: Neither is *wrong* but both are clumsy.  Why not *I witnessed nature in her cruelty* or *I witnessed the cruelty of nature* or *I witnessed cruel nature*?  And don't complain that I have dropped *moment* from the sentence, it takes more than a moment for a few wolves to kill a few deer!

Comment: The plural of 'deer' is... 'deer'. You're imagining a scene where a few wolves attack a few **deer**.